# Get distinct elements with mongoose and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have data store in mongo as follows with the collectio named **`_listing`** .

```
{   "_id": "58a1ddcb8850c027298c4dc8",   "name": "Listing 1",  
 "description": "",   "ticket": {
     "amount": 2,
     "type": "electronic",
     "splitType": 2,
     "seating": [
       {
         "category": 1,
         "section": 2,
         "row": 2
       },
       {
        "category": 3,
         "section": "uiui",
         "row": 33
       }
     ]   },   "metadata": {
     "user": {},
     "event": {},
     "venue": {}   },   "listingId": "aabb1cb6-4e79-4d48-9451-e5247230d397" }
```

I want to retrieve unique categories from the above.

Here is my code.

**DBhelper.js**

```
distinct: function (model, conditons, projection, options, distinctKey) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                options = options || {};
                projection = projection || {};
                model.find(conditons, projection, options).distinct(distinctKey, function (error, data) {
                    if (error)
                        console.log("error is" + err);
                        reject(error);
                    console.log("data is " + data);
                    resolve(data);
                })
            })
        }
```

and i call the above function as below,

```
dbHelper.distinct(mongoose.model('_listing'), {}, {}, { 'ticket.seating.category': '1' }, 'ticket.seating.category', function (error, data) {
                console.log(data);
                callback(data);
            });
```

I cannot get the data get printed in the above method, while data get printed in the dbhelper function. what is the issue?

Comment: The distinct function in DBHelper.js returns a promise, don't you mean to use it as `dbHelper.distinct(mongoose.model('_listing'), {}, {}, { 'ticket.seating.category': '1' }, 'ticket.seating.category').then(function(data){ console.log(data); })`?

Comment: @chridam no it dint work, same issue

Comment: is it throwing some error in the distinct function?

Comment: @RaviShankar no error is thrown, i can see the data printed